# Django runserver stop

Tags: django, postgresql

I running Django localhost server with PostgreSQL database:`python manage.py runserver`
But when I use the browser to consult the project, the server stops like I put in the console `Ctrl + C`. I don't get any error messege from Python, so I don't know whats happen.

I got this information from Windows Events Monitor. I don't know if it means something to anybody, but I understand it is a crash report.

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Windows Error Reporting 

  - EventID 1001 

   [ Qualifiers]  0 

   Level 4 

   Task 0 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2018-09-18T21:23:09.081612800Z 

   EventRecordID 1121 

   Channel Application 

   Computer DESKTOP-UMHL2MO 

   Security 


- EventData 

   2255961328469566825 
   1 
   APPCRASH 
   No disponible 
   0 
   python.exe 
   3.7.150.1013 
   5b330dc6 
   StackHash_89ce 
   10.0.17134.1 
   c8733c73 
   c0000374 
   PCH_CF_FROM_ntdll+0x00069ABC 


   \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER3360.tmp.dmp \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER340D.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER341E.tmp.xml \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER341E.tmp.csv \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER343E.tmp.txt 
   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_python.exe_54cf6c8aeb3ae10789acd854ed6a82b72d1c7c1_d4f4c736_01a13796 

   0 
   b7e6ab6d-2a75-4996-9e5e-c5d132578749 
   268435456 
   2bfa2eb7e405e3f06f4ec8e02a726569 
   0
```

Comment: Hi, as much as we would like to help you it is hard for volunteers here guess what is happening unless you update your question with a simple, reproducible example. That said, I would check if you are not calling `exit()` by mistake or something like that.

Comment: Well It's just breaks, I don't write anything in the console, I just run the server, then I go ot the browser to acces the project and just stops, I go back to the console and the server stops with no error message at all. I would like to give you a reproducible example, but there is not one. It was workin and it just stopped after a Windows update. I removed the updates, and nothing.

Comment: I see, but from the question we don't have enough information for reproducing your problem on our local environments and we don't have access to your environment so we are stuck do divination. Have you tried creating a new, small Django project in order to see if the problem is with the environment or within your application?

Comment: I created a new project and It works, but I recreated my project and pulled it from git, and It doens´t work neither. It happens only in windows, in mac it works